# Timing in javascript for html5 music games/apps

Tags: javascript, html, timing

I'd really to start work soon on a series of music based apps for [www.daveconservatoire.org](http://www.daveconservatoire.org) .

The thing holding me back at the moment is that from reading various articles/posts etc I can't work out whether it is realistic to use javascript to produce accurate timing in applications.  We are talking correct to maybe 10ms.

For example, one of the more simple applications would be a metrnonme that can be set to tick at a given interval - 60BMP, for example, would require the ticking sound to be played once every second.

Is this achievable with javascript/html5?  All the examples of metronomes that I've found have been written in flash, presumably because it is difficult to work with accurate timing in JS.

Comment: This is likely a good read for you (though potentially slightly outdated) http://nerdplusart.com/why-is-there-flash-in-the-html5-version-of-cut-the-rope

Answer (score 3):

I found your question to be interesting so I decided to do a little test on my own. Javascript's setInterval function does not seem to be sufficient to do a metronome type application. So I built a custom "class" that uses the current time instead and it seems to be accurate within +-3 ms. Your mileage may vary. The code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/66YJz/.

```
// Custom timer class

// f = function to call
// m = ms
function timer(f, m)
{
    var target_time = (new Date()).getTime() + m;
    var margin = 3;

    setInterval(function(){
        var now = (new Date()).getTime();
        var dif = target_time - now;
        // If within acceptable timeframe, call function
        if (dif <= margin && dif >= -margin) {
            target_time = now + m + dif;
            f();
        }
        // For some reason we missed the time frame.
        // Skip and move on to next
        if (dif < -margin ) {
           target_time += m;
           //margin += 1;
        }
    },
    1);
}
```

I just whipped this up so I'm sure there is plenty of room for improvement.

Comment: I had a go with this and found that under normal circumstances (tab in focus, not much else going on) it does skip a fairly significant amount. It goes very wrong with tab out of focus, which is fair enough. Coming back to it after some time away (computer on sleep), though, it didn't seem to recover itself. If I make any improvements, I guess I'll post here.

Comment: A modified fiddle with some more diagnostics http://jsfiddle.net/66YJz/1/ one example of something that makes it skip a lot is scrolling the JavaScript pane.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [work-in-progress specification for High-Resolution Time in JavaScript](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/HighResolutionTime/Overview.html).

Until that is usefully available, though, the situation is trickier.

I've found an interesting tutorial on this subject: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/

It goes into some detail of the various issues involved, and suggests approaches that seem apt, particularly if it is WebAudio that you want to sequence. I have yet to put it to the test myself, but here are some salient quotes from the article to describe the problems and an overview of how they can be effectively approached:

> The worst part of the JavaScript timing APIs are that although Date.now()’s millisecond precision doesn’t sound too bad to live with, the actual callback of timer events in JavaScript (through window.setTimeout() or window.setInterval) can easily be skewed by tens of milliseconds or more by layout, rendering, garbage collection, and XMLHTTPRequest and other callbacks - in short, by any number of things happening on the main execution thread.

...

> The way that [the given example] manages to allow tempo control while maintaining rock-solid timing is a collaboration: a setTimeout timer that fires once every so often, and sets up Web Audio scheduling in the future for individual notes. The setTimeout timer basically just checks to see if any notes are going to need to be scheduled “soon” based on the current tempo, and then schedules them...

They also suggest that requestAnimationFrame can be used in place of setTimeout, allowing precise synchronisation with graphics; this would be a natural approach for games.

The tutorial doesn't cover what one might do if it is not WebAudio one is trying to sequence. In my somewhat obscure case, I would actually like to control an instance of SuperCollider over the network. In order for this to work, I can adapt the suggested approach by specifying the time that execution should occur as part of each OSC message, and allowing the scsynth scheduler to take the place of the WebAudio one.

There may be other situations which are not so readily adaptable, though: for example, controlling an ordinary MIDI synth with note messages would not be able to work with this approach. The authors of the [draft WebMIDI specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/webmidi/) anticipate it being used with the High Resolution Time API I mention at the beginning of this answer.